# python2.7 and beautiful soup 4 (bs4)

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I ran into another problem, I'm tied to using python2.7, can't use any newer, also I'm using beautiful soup 4 with python2.7

Anyways my question is, how do I extract following data from all .. sections from a website's code?

```
<tr id="id-gainers-adtoken-1h">
<td class="text-right">
1
</td>
<td class="no-wrap currency-name">
<img src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/adtoken.png" class="currency-logo" alt="adToken">
<a href="/currencies/adtoken/">adToken</a>
</td>

<td class="text-left">ADT</td>

<td class="no-wrap text-right">
<a href="/currencies/adtoken/#markets" class="volume" data-usd="45657000.0" data-btc="4103.75">$45,657,000</a>
</td>

<td class="no-wrap text-right">
<a href="/currencies/adtoken/#markets" class="price" data-usd="0.198131" data-btc="1.78084e-05">$0.198131</a>
</td>

<td class="no-wrap percent-1h  positive_change  text-right" data-usd="36.36" data-btc="33.02">36.36%</td>
</tr>
```

I need following data:

```
"adtoken" and "1h" from first line
<tr id="id-gainers-adtoken-1h">

36.36% from
<td class="no-wrap percent-1h  positive_change  text-right" data-usd="36.36" data-btc="33.02">36.36%</td>
```

I'd like to collect all those values in a list of dictionaries, like so:

```
biggest_gainers = [
{ "name": "adtoken", "timeframe": "1h", "gain": "36.36%" },
{ "name": "spectre-dividend", "timeframe": "1h", "gain": "34.34%" } ]
```

my code so far is writing everything of the html code that contains "('tr')" to a file. From here I couldn't figure out how to continue, I've tried multiple split scenarios, deleting the indexes and also removing the last n character from the string with [:-3] after reading the file line by line.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib2
from time import sleep

url = urllib2.urlopen('https://coinmarketcap.com/gainers-losers/')
soup = bs(url)


print(soup)
with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as f:

    for item in soup('tr'):
        f.write(str(item))
    f.close()
```

I believe my general approach to this is completely wrong, as I should not need to write it to a file first and then parse that file.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: You clearly can use BS4 with Python 2.7: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4

Comment: Yeah I just installed it and trying it out now, but so far no luck in regards of what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Don't use BeautifulSoup to parse HTML from CoinMarketCap.  They have an API!

```
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/
```

The easiest way to load it is:

```
import requests

requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/').json()
```

Comment: Yeah I know there is an API, but since the API is not giving any information that I'm trying to acquire it won't be any help to me.

Comment: @ForumStudiologe: What information is missing in the API?  It looks to me like it's all there.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the code is below for anyone who is trying to achieve the same:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib2
from time import sleep

url = urllib2.urlopen('https://coinmarketcap.com/gainers-losers/')
soup = bs(url, "html.parser")


table_1h = soup.find("div", attrs={"id":"gainers-1h", "class": "tab-pane"})
headings_1h = [th.get_text() for th in table_1h.find("tr").find_all("th")]

table_24h = soup.find("div", attrs={"id":"gainers-24h", "class": "tab-pane"})
headings_24h = [th.get_text() for th in table_24h.find("tr").find_all("th")]

table_7d = soup.find("div", attrs={"id":"gainers-7d", "class": "tab-pane"})
headings_7d = [th.get_text() for th in table_7d.find("tr").find_all("th")]


print("================================================================")
biggest_gainers_1h = []
for row in table_1h.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    dataset = zip(headings_1h, (td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td")))
    coinInfoName    = str(dataset[1][1].strip('\r\n'))
    coinInfoSymbol  = str(dataset[2][1].strip('\r\n'))
    coinInfoVolume  = str(dataset[3][1].strip('\r\n').replace("$",""))
    coinInfoPrice   = float(dataset[4][1].strip('\r\n').replace("$",""))
    coinInfoPercent =  float(dataset[5][1].strip('\r\n').replace("%",""))

    biggest_gainers_1h.append({"Name": str(coinInfoName), "Symbol": str(coinInfoSymbol), "Volume": str(coinInfoVolume), "Price": float(coinInfoPrice), "Percentage": float(coinInfoPercent)})

for item in biggest_gainers_1h:
    print(item)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print("================================================================")
biggest_gainers_24h = []
for row in table_24h.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    dataset = zip(headings_24h, (td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td")))
    coinInfoName    = str(dataset[1][1].strip('\r\n'))
    coinInfoSymbol  = str(dataset[2][1].strip('\r\n'))
    coinInfoVolume  = str(dataset[3][1].strip('\r\n').replace("$",""))
    coinInfoPrice   = float(dataset[4][1].strip('\r\n').replace("$",""))
    coinInfoPercent =  float(dataset[5][1].strip('\r\n').replace("%",""))

    biggest_gainers_24h.append({"Name": str(coinInfoName), "Symbol": str(coinInfoSymbol), "Volume": str(coinInfoVolume), "Price": float(coinInfoPrice), "Percentage": float(coinInfoPercent)})

for item in biggest_gainers_24h:
    print(item)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print("================================================================")
biggest_gainers_7d = []
for row in table_7d.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    dataset = zip(headings_7d, (td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td")))
    coinInfoName    = str(dataset[1][1].strip('\r\n'))
    coinInfoSymbol  = str(dataset[2][1].strip('\r\n'))
    coinInfoVolume  = str(dataset[3][1].strip('\r\n').replace("$",""))
    coinInfoPrice   = float(dataset[4][1].strip('\r\n').replace("$",""))
    coinInfoPercent =  float(dataset[5][1].strip('\r\n').replace("%",""))

    biggest_gainers_7d.append({"Name": str(coinInfoName), "Symbol": str(coinInfoSymbol), "Volume": str(coinInfoVolume), "Price": float(coinInfoPrice), "Percentage": float(coinInfoPercent)})

for item in biggest_gainers_7d:
    print(item)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print("================================================================")
```